# python how to change the time format from csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, time

After using `pd.read_csv()`, I get the data bellow. But in the first column, the time format is wrong. Could you please tell me how to correct it? Thanks.
The data is like below, the first column should be 2017/4/10 9:25:00 rather than 42835.39236.

```
     datetime   open   high    low  close
0  42835.39236  20.72  20.72  20.72  20.72
1  42835.39583  20.72  20.72  20.67  20.67
2  42835.39653  20.66  20.67  20.62  20.63
3  42835.39722  20.63  20.65  20.59  20.59
4  42835.39792  20.59  20.59  20.52  20.52
```

Comment: How does the input look like? Are you passing any arguments to pd.read_csv()?

Comment: It looks like some relative time, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the correct date use:

```
import datetime as dt

df['datetime'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['datetime'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
```

Which will produce:

```
                 datetime   open   high    low  close
0 2017-04-10 09:24:59.904  20.72  20.72  20.72  20.72
1 2017-04-10 09:29:59.712  20.72  20.72  20.67  20.67
2 2017-04-10 09:31:00.192  20.66  20.67  20.62  20.63
3 2017-04-10 09:31:59.808  20.63  20.65  20.59  20.59
4 2017-04-10 09:33:00.288  20.59  20.59  20.52  20.52
```

**EDIT**

To split `datetime` into `date` and `time` use:

```
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['datetime'].dt.ceil('min').dt.time
df
#                 datetime   open   high    low  close        date      time
#0 2017-04-10 09:24:59.904  20.72  20.72  20.72  20.72  2017-04-10  09:25:00
#1 2017-04-10 09:29:59.712  20.72  20.72  20.67  20.67  2017-04-10  09:30:00
#2 2017-04-10 09:31:00.192  20.66  20.67  20.62  20.63  2017-04-10  09:32:00
#3 2017-04-10 09:31:59.808  20.63  20.65  20.59  20.59  2017-04-10  09:32:00
#4 2017-04-10 09:33:00.288  20.59  20.59  20.52  20.52  2017-04-10  09:34:00
```

Comment: That's correct. And I also want to ask how to split the first column to two parts. Like the first row is "2017-04-10 09:24:59.904 ", I want to get two columns: 2017-04-10 and 09:25:00. Thanks. @zipa

Comment: I get it. The last question is since the time is too long. How can I change the time into our normal way. eg, 09:24:59.904000 change to 09:25:00. @zipa

Answer (score 3):

Just use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
In [741]: df
Out[741]: 
          date
0  42835.39236

In [742]: df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

In [743]: df
Out[743]: 
                           date
0 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000042835
```

Pandas will convert it to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
```

try this:

```
tt = pd.read_csv('aa.csv', parse_dates=True)

print(tt)
```

It will print as follows / as per expectation, sorry I am new in this stackoverflow, but this answer works.

```
datetime        open       high       low       close

9:25:00 AM      20.72      20.72      20.72      20.72

9:30:00 AM      20.72      20.72      20.67      20.67

9:31:00 AM      20.66      20.67      20.62      20.63

9:32:00 AM      20.63      20.65      20.59      20.59

9:33:00 AM      20.59      20.59      20.52      20.52
```